# How can adding a reflector to a half-wave dipole (in a Yagi Uda antenna) increase the gain by more than 3dB?

Tags: antenna, superposition, dipole

I have been designing a Yagi Uda antenna using CST Microwave Studio.

For a half-wave dipole the directivity (at 1.3GHz) was 2.116dBi.

[image: half-wave dipole farfield directivity]

After I added a Reflector, the directivity improved to 6.074dBi.

[image: Two element Yagi Uda]

This is an increase of 3.958dB - more than double!

I am trying to understand how this is possible?  How can the gain more than double?  If I understand correctly, the reflector *reflects* the fields from the dipole back to the opposite direction.  Thus in the best case scenario I will get complete super-position of the fields.  Therefore I should find a maximum increase of 3dB - not more!

Thanks!

Comment: An improvement of "6.074 dBi" (once you set the benchmark) is 6.074 dB

Comment: @Andyaka Right, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think in 3 dimensions, not just 2.  Not only do you get superposition forward along the axis of the reflector placement, but the energy from the off-axis fields is changed (and is conserved, so it has to go somewhere, e.g. potentially forward).

Answer (score 1):

The plain dipole has a "beam width" of 360° — it radiates equally well in all directions in the normal plane.

When you add the reflector, the -3 dB beam width is not simply reduced to 180° — it's actually significantly less than that, more like 120°. Since gain is more or less inversely proportional to beam width, this accounts for the numbers you're getting.